# How to get a mouse position in Puppeteer-sharp?

Tags: c#, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

Help get the current mouse position in puppeteer-sharp, I tried adapting Node.JS code for puppeteer sharp, but I can't do it.

```
page.evaluate(() => {
   document.onmousemove = function(e){
           mouseX = e.offsetX;
           mouseY = e.offsetY;
           console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
   }
})
```

Tried this, but I always get an x coordinate of zero:

```
var xOffset = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync<int>("window.offsetX");
MessageBox.Show(xOffset.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the evaluate function won't get what you write in the `console.log`. You need to return something.
As you are waiting for an event you can return a promise and resolve that promise inside the event.

```
page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<Point>(@"() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.onmousemove = function(e){
      mouseX = e.offsetX;
      mouseY = e.offsetY;
      resolve({x: mouseX, y: mouseY});
    };
  });
}");
```

Comment: Would `page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<Point>(@"() => 
  new Promise(resolve => 
    document.onmousemove = (e) =>
      resolve({x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY}));
");` work?

Comment: No. The generic type your are passing to the evaluate function has to match the value you are returning. That’s why I’m settting that to Point. But it can be anything with and x/y property

Comment: @hardkoded Could you give a small example of how to return a promise and resolve that promise inside the event? I seem to have tried almost everything in the last incomplete two days, but my skills are not enough to handle it. I need a method that returns the current cursor position. Maybe if you don't mind giving me an example of such code? Thank you!

Comment: My example does that @Мистер

Comment: @hardkoded when I call this line of code, I get an AggregateException error `MessageBox.Show(GetCursorPos.Result.ToString());` I'm not sure if the mistakes fit in one comment... But I'll try)

Comment: @hardkoded made a screenshot https://ibb.co/mTF87mb in the comments even two System.AggregateException will not fit)